# DSL query for time range starting at a specific log

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, dsl

I'm new to elasticsearch and I have data consisting of DNS queries which looks
like this:

[image: DNS_queries_table]

I need to look for a specific domain and display it, along with all the domains that occured given time before.

For example when I'm looking for stackoverflow.com, I need to display stackoverflow.com and all the domains that were visited e.g. 15 seconds before it.
I understand that the data also needs to be grouped by clients before I do this.
Any idea how to do it with DSL query?
Many thanks!

Comment: If I understand your need, You query would be composed of a time_range gte: @reftimestamp lte: @reftimestamp+5min, a term aggregation on domains and a top_hit sub aggregation

Comment: I'll try it, thanks!